# My database is not migrating properly to my live Heroku App (Coursework)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, heroku-postgres

I am doing some coursework through an online bootcamp and we are learning Ruby on Rails as well as implementing the project through Heroku.

I have everything working absolutely fine in my development environment. I ran the migrations for my database and pushed everything (to my knowledge) to Heroku. When I try to run the `heroku run rake db:migrate` command the output is:

> Running rake db:migrate on kpez-app... up, run.4076
>     ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (3.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

When I pull up my live app the database is missing.

Comment: How do you know the database is missing? Is there an error? If so, post it

Comment: Have you added a database addon to your app account on heroku? They offer a [free postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) service that should be fine for what you need.

Comment: have you tried restarting the server? "heroku restart"

Comment: I am not receiving an error that I know of. On my local environment it shows the products that I have added and after pushing everything to the live app as I have done before then running the migrate it shows broken link icons for one product image that was used on an earlier exercise. I am using their postgres service as well! I just tried restarting the server and it still shows the same thing.